# How to express a retarded time function?

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction

I have been messing around with Lienard-Wiechert potentials and am having some trouble properly expressing my retarded time function. As of this moment the function looks like so

```
tr[r_, t_] = t - Norm[r - rs[t]]/c
```

where **rs** is the position of the source charge and **r** is the position of the field point. Since we are dealing with retarded fields however, the position of the source charge should be taken at the retarded time **tr**. Problem is, that would mean I'd have **rs[tr]** in the function *for* **tr**, which ends up being recursive, I think. How do I solve for **tr** then? Does it require that I use RSolve or Solve, and if so what's the right way of doing that?

Comment: Why as of the moment function looks like `tr[r_, t_] = t - Norm[r - rs[t]]/c`? This is wrong equation, therefore your question also is wrong. Please, ask direct question about solution of retarded time equation in a form of `tr==t-Norm[r-rs[tr]]/c` vs `r={x,y,z}` and `rs[tr_]:={xs[tr],ys[tr],zs[tr}` for given functions `xs, ys, zs`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retarded time in general case defined as solution of equation $t_r=t-|\vec{r}-\vec{r_b}(t_r)|/c$, where $r=(x,y,z), r_b(t)=(x_b(t),y_b(t),z_b(t))$. The code to compute $t_r=t_r(t,x,y,z)$ is given by (here $c=1$)

```
R1 = {x, y, z};
R2 = {xb[t], yb[t], zb[t]};
    R = R1 - R2;
tr[t_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
  r /. FindRoot[
    r == t - Sqrt[(x - xb[r])^2 + (y - yb[r])^2 + (z - zb[r])^2], {r, 
     t - Sqrt[(x - xb[t])^2 + (y - yb[t])^2 + (z - zb[t])^2]}];
```

Example of usage for a charge moving along `x` axis with a speed defined as follows

```
v0 = .99;
        xb[t_] := v0*Tanh[t];
        yb[t_] := 0.;
        zb[t_] := 0.;


Plot3D[tr[t, x, 0, 0], {t, -1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 25, 
 MaxRecursion -> 2, MeshStyle -> White, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific", AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 1]
Using `tr` we can compute electric and magnetic field

```
Vt = D[R2, t, t];
    V0 = D[R2, t];  
    Ev = ((1 - V0 . V0)*(R - V0*Norm[R]) + 
              Cross[R, Cross[(R - V0*Norm[R]), Vt]])/(Norm[R] - R . V0)^3 /. 
           t -> tr[t, x, y, z];B = Cross[R, Ev]/Norm[R];
```

Visualization

```
StreamDensityPlot[
 Drop[B, 1] /. {x -> 1, t -> -.25}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the detailed help! I am taking the time to fully parse exactly what you did. You used NumericQ so that tr will only be evaluated when the arguments [t, x, y, z] are numeric, yes? And then FindRoot finds a solution to the equation r ==  t - Sqrt[(x - xb[r])^2 + (y - yb[r])^2 + (z - zb[r])^2] near r = t - Sqrt[(x - xb[t])^2 + (y - yb[t])^2 + (z - zb[t])^2], which is meant to solve the recursive equation for the retarded time whenever r is called? How do you apply it to potentials? I tried doing so but Mathematica just keeps running, it never gets a 3D plot out.

Comment: Specifically, after setting Rs = {xs[t], ys[t], zs[t]}, Rp = {x, y, z}, and R = Rp - Rs;, I went through the same steps for writing out the equation for tr. I replaced r with Rp in the functions for the potentials as well as all occurrences of Rp - Rs with R. I then expressed the electric field as LWEField[Rp_, t_] := - LWSgrad@t - LWVdt@t /.t -> tr[t, x, y, z]. I tried to plot the field using VectorPlot3D[Evaluate@LWEField[Rp, t] /.t -> -.25, {x,-1,1}, {y,-1,1}, {z,-1,1}], but Mathematica just kept running and would not produce a plot. I know that's a lot, but any suggestions there?

Comment: The field you are trying to plot is singular. So you can't plot this field around `y=0&&z=0` in my example. Try for instance `VectorPlot3D[Ev /. t -> -.25, {x, -1, 1}, {y, .1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}] `.

Comment: I apologize, I do not get what you mean by my field being "singular." Are you saying that it has a singularity? How then do I express the fields using time retarded potentials and get them to plot? For my project I am avoiding direct field expressions, so my electric and magnetic field equations need to be dependent on the potentials.

Comment: Field of point charge has a singularity. Why for your project field needs to be dependent on potential?

Comment: For my project, I am showing that using Mathematica to turn the potentials into fields is easier than directly coding the Jefimenko Equations with retarded time involved. So I need to have expressions for the potentials in terms of retarded time

Comment: I think that this is nice question for discussion in a new topic.

Comment: I once again went and did just that. Take a look whenever you are able.